# Вывод информации о COM-порте

Tags: c#, winforms, com-порт

Надо написать программу, которая будет выводить в ComboBox список подключенных Com портов. При выборе одного из этих портов в элемент управления TexBox выводятся данные об этом порте. С первой задачей я справился, но вот со второй проблема- не могу получить данные о конкретном порте. Как это можно сделать?
Код программы:

```
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;

namespace COM_Ports_Finder
{
  public partial class Main : Form
  {
    // Создаем поток
    Thread Com_Refresher;
    // Флаг работы потока
    bool To_Work = true;
    // Предыдущие порты
    string[] Last_Ports = new string[0];

    public Main()
    {
        // Инициализация
        InitializeComponent();
        // Задаем потоку задачу
        Com_Refresher = new Thread(Refresh_Com_Ports);
        // Запускаем поток
        Com_Refresher.Start();
    }


    private void Refresh_Com_Ports()
    // Функция обновления порта
    {
        // Пока надо работать
        while (To_Work)
        {

            // Получаем список доступных портов
            string[] Ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            // Если порты не совпадают
            if (!Is_Arrays_Equeals(Ports, Last_Ports))
            {
                // Очистить поля
                Clear_Fields();
                // Добавить порты в список
                Add_Ports(Ports);
                // Изменить размер Last_Ports
                System.Array.Resize(ref Last_Ports, Ports.Length);
                // Записать данные в Last_Ports
                Last_Ports = Ports;
            }
            // Останавливаем поток на 100 мс
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }  

    private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    // Закрытие формы
    {
        // Останавливаем поток
        To_Work = false;
        // Останавливаем поток
        Com_Refresher.Abort();
        // Ждем остановки потока
        while(Com_Refresher.ThreadState != ThreadState.Aborted);
    }

    private void Com_Ports_CBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    // Выбор значения в CBox
    {
        // Найденные порты
        ManagementObjectCollection Ports;
        // Поисковик данных
        ManagementObjectSearcher Ports_Found;
        // Находим порты по запросу
        Ports_Found = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_SerialPort");
        // Записываем полученные данные
        Ports = Ports_Found.Get();
        // Для всех полученных данных
        foreach (ManagementObject Port in Ports)
        {
            // Выдать информацию
            Information_TBox.Text  = Port["DeviceID"].ToString() + "\r\n";
            Information_TBox.Text += Port["PNPDeviceID"].ToString() + "\r\n";
            Information_TBox.Text += Port["Name"].ToString() + "\r\n";
            Information_TBox.Text += Port["Caption"].ToString() + "\r\n";
            Information_TBox.Text += Port["Description"].ToString() + "\r\n";
            Information_TBox.Text += Port["ProviderType"].ToString() + "\r\n";
            Information_TBox.Text += Port["Status"].ToString();
        }
    }

    private void Clear_Fields()
    // Функция очистки полей
    {
        // В основном потоке
        Com_Ports_CBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
        {
            // Очищаем CBox
            Com_Ports_CBox.Items.Clear();
            // Очищаем TBox
            Information_TBox.Text = "";
        });
    }

    private void Add_Ports(string[] Ports)
    // Функция добавления портов в список
    {
        // Для всех портов
        foreach (string Port in Ports)
        {
            // В основном потоке
            Com_Ports_CBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                // Добавляем элемент в CBox
                Com_Ports_CBox.Items.Add(Port);
            });
        }
    }

    private bool Is_Arrays_Equeals(string[] First, string[] Second)
    // Проверка массивов на идентичность
    {
        // Совпадают ли порты
        bool Is_Equeals = true;
        // Если порты одинаковых размеров
        if (First.Length == Second.Length)
        {
            // Для всех портов
            for (int i = 0; i < First.Length; i++)
            {
                // Если порты не совпадают
                if (First[i] != Second[i])
                {
                    // Порты не совпадают
                    Is_Equeals = false;
                }
            }
        }
        // Если порты не одного размера
        else
        {
            // Порты не совпадают
            Is_Equeals = false;
        }
        // Вернуть ответ
        return Is_Equeals;
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE: выполнение команды `wmic path Win32_PnPEntity where "ClassGuid = '{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}'" get / value`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно можно просто сделать выборку из *Win32_SerialPort* по *DeviceID* (он содержит имя порта, возвращаемое *GetPortNames*):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;

namespace WmiTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        

        /*Возвращает информацию о последовательном порте с указанным именем*/
        public string GetComPortInformation(string name)
        {
            ManagementObjectCollection mbsList = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2000);            

            ManagementObjectSearcher mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
            "SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort WHERE DeviceID = '"+name+"'"
            );

            using (mbs)
            {
                mbsList = mbs.Get();

                foreach (ManagementObject mo in mbsList)
                {
                    object val = mo["Name"];
                    if (val != null) sb.AppendLine( val.ToString());

                    foreach (var p in mo.Properties)
                    {
                        sb.Append( "* " + p.Name + ": ");
                        if (p.Value != null)
                        {
                            sb.Append( p.Value.ToString());
                        }
                        else sb.Append( "null");
                        sb.AppendLine();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string com_port = comboBox1.SelectedText; //Имя порта, например "COM1"
            textBox1.Text = GetComPortInformation(com_port);
        }

    }
}
```

Это сработает для всех физических COM-портов (ну, тех которые система считает физическими - т.е. для которых в диспетчере можно настроить скорость и прочие параметры). Для некоторых виртуальных портов это может не сработать. Это относится главным образом к виртуальным порта USB-устройств, работающих с нестандартным драйвером - DeviceID у таких устройств начинается не с "USB\", а с вендорно-специфичной строки. Тогда, если приведенный запрос не вернул ничего, можно попробовать как-то так (вернет меньше свойств):

> "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity where ClassGuid = '{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}' and Service <> 'Parport' AND Name like '%" + name + "%'"

Однако и такой способ - не лучший вариант, так как он основан на фильтрации по имени устройства, которое может и не содержать внутреннего имени порта. Более правильно связывать *Win32_PnpEntity* с портом через *PnpDeviceID*, используя параметр *PortName* в ветке реестра `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\(PnpDeviceID)\DeviceParameters`. Это реализовано в следующем примере, более громоздком, но позволяющим корректно обработать большинство ситуаций и вывести максимальное количество доступных сведений.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace WmiTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /*Получение имени COM-порта по его PnpDeviceID*/
        public string PortNameFromID(string PnpDeviceID)
        {
            object result = Registry.GetValue(
                "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Enum\\" + PnpDeviceID + "\\Device Parameters",
                "PortName", "");

            if (result != null) return result as string;
            else return "";
        }

        /*Возвращает информацию о последовательном порте с указанным именем*/
        public string GetComPortInformation(string name)
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher mbs;
            ManagementObjectCollection mbsList = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2000);
            object val;

            //попытка получить данные из Win32_SerialPort
            mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort WHERE DeviceID = '"+name+"'");

            using (mbs)
            {
                mbsList = mbs.Get();

                foreach (ManagementObject mo in mbsList)
                {
                    val = mo["Name"];
                    if (val != null) sb.AppendLine( val.ToString());

                    //порт найден, возвращаем данные
                    foreach (var p in mo.Properties)
                    {
                        sb.Append( "* " + p.Name + ": ");
                        if (p.Value != null)
                        {
                            sb.Append( p.Value.ToString());
                        }
                        else sb.Append( "null");
                        sb.AppendLine();
                    }
                    return sb.ToString();
                }//end foreach                       
            }

            //порт не найден, выберем все последовательные порты из Win32_PnPEntity
            mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
            "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity where ClassGuid = '{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}' and Service <> 'Parport'"
            );

            using (mbs)
            {
                mbsList = mbs.Get();

                foreach (ManagementObject mo in mbsList)                
                {
                    //находим идентификатор
                    val = mo["PnpDeviceID"];
                    if (val == null) continue;

                    string id = val.ToString();
                    if (id.Length == 0) continue;

                    //находим имя порта для данного PnpDeviceID в реестре
                    if (PortNameFromID(id) == name)
                    {
                        //порт найден, возвращаем данные
                        sb.Clear();
                        val = mo["Name"];
                        if (val != null) sb.AppendLine(val.ToString());

                        foreach (var p in mo.Properties)
                        {
                            sb.Append("* " + p.Name + ": ");
                            if (p.Value != null)
                            {
                                sb.Append(p.Value.ToString());
                            }
                            else sb.Append("null");
                            sb.AppendLine();
                        }
                        return sb.ToString();
                    }                    
                }//end foreach          

            }

            return "Информация не найдена";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string com_port = comboBox1.SelectedText; 
             textBox1.Text = GetComPortInformation(com_port); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Запрос возвращает все тоже самое, что и мой. Данные возвращаются только для COM1, а для остальных ничего нет....

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov А от каких устройств порты не видит?
 Скиньте результат выполнения команды `wmic path Win32_PnPEntity where "ClassGuid = '{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}'" get /value` на вашей машине

Comment: Сделал. Результат выполнения в вопросе внизу

Comment: Заработало. Правильный запрос- `"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity where ClassGuid = '{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}' and Service <> 'Parport' AND Name like '%" + name + "%'"`

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov Видимо Serial Port не возвращал COM5 из-за нестандартных USB-драйверов. На самом деле, второй способ не совсем правильный, так как фильтрация по имени устройства это костыль. В большинстве случаев работает, но 100% уверенности нет.

Comment: Нет, я получал все подключенные порты, но вот данные из Win_32 я получал только для COM1