# Мне требуется получить VID и PID по имени COM-порта, возможно ли такое?

Tags: c#, com-порт, serialport

```
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        foreach(string port in ports)
        {
            ...
        }
```

В цикле хочу проверять по имени COM-порта его PID и VID на совпадение с некой строкой, есть какой-то способ?

Comment: Не ыакт, что в тему, но вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50544526/12888024)

Comment: В WMI можно получить VID и PID косвенно как часть Device ID. Вот здесь есть примеры: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798312/240512